# Converting tab delimited text to CSV WITHOUT CR inside quotes in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Using the below powershell command to convert a tab delimited text to a CSV.

```
Import-Csv inbound.txt -Delimiter `t | Export-Csv inbound.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

All goes well, the file is converted to CSV with quotes around each field. HOWEVER the resulting file has a CR inside the last quote on each line distorting the values of the last column (qty) .. 
For example

```
"sku","Quantity Available
"
"ABCD","10
"
```

(notice the line break after the Available and after the value 10, which is before the end quote)

Any idea how to get rid of the carriage return within the quote at the end of each line?

Comment: So your original data has the carriage return in it?

Comment: Also, what OS are you on? Some example pre conversion data might help as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your text file has messed up line endings, such as `\n\r` instead of `\r\n`, or possibly some oddball Unicode character.  Try:

```
Get-Content $FileName | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Trim()
} | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" |
Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!